# Como faço para uma celula ser botão numa tabela?

Tags: javascript, html, table, button

```
<div id=table>
  <tr id="tablebottom">
        <th>
            <h5>Hoje</h5> 
        </th>
        <th>
            <h5>Amanhã</h5>
        </th>
  </tr> 
</div>
```

A minha dúvida é como conseguir fazer com que toda a celula seja um botão que me abra uma div que não está visivel. Ou seja, ao clicar por ex em hoje aparece uma div por cima da tabela com mais informações inerentes ao dia..

Alguém me pode ajudar??

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode usar Jquery? O que pretende fazer com o botão?

Comment: Amigo sem o código fica complicado. Posta o que vc tem ai de html/css/etc... e fica mais fácil para te responder

Comment: @i_like_trans aquilo que eu quero é que ao carregar no "hoje" "amanhã" etc apareça uma especie de pop-up (ou um div centrado na página) que vai conter mais informação dentro desse div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, é mais ou menos isso que precisa, só implementar na sua necessidade.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
        height: 500px;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 100px auto 0;
        background: #e3e3e3;
        grid-auto-rows: 75% 25%;
    }

    .container-aux{
        height: 375px;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 100px auto 0;
        background: white;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        border: 2px solid black;
    }

    .container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
        height: 500px;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 100px auto 0;
        background: #e3e3e3;
        grid-auto-rows: 75% 25%;

    }

    .item{
        border: 2px solid black;
    }

    .hidden{
        display: none;
    }

</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item item-link" data-dia="1">Hoje</div>
    <div class="item item-link" data-dia="2">Amanhã</div>
    <div class="item item-link" data-dia="3">Sáb</div>
    <div class="item item-link" data-dia="4">Dom</div>
    <div class="item item-link" data-dia="5">Seg</div>
    <div class="item item-link" data-dia="6">Ter</div>
    <div class="item item-link" data-dia="7">Quar</div>
</div>


<div class="container-aux dia1 hidden">Previsão de Hoje</div>
<div class="container-aux dia2 hidden">Previsão de Amanhã</div>
<div class="container-aux dia3 hidden">Previsão de Sabado</div>
<div class="container-aux dia4 hidden">Previsão de Domingo</div>
<div class="container-aux dia5 hidden">Previsão de Segunda</div>
<div class="container-aux dia6 hidden">Previsão de Terça</div>
<div class="container-aux dia7 hidden">Previsão de Quarta</div>


<script>
    $('.item').on('click', function(){
        let dia = $(this).data('dia');

        $.each($('.container-aux'), function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass('hidden')){
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
            }
        });

        console.log($('.dia'+dia));
        $('.dia'+dia).removeClass('hidden');

    })
</script>
```